# ASP.Net MVC 5: Best way to design Role Based Access system for web based product

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i may have to develop a ERP system which would not be public facing web site rather it will be used by various user of a specific organization. i am looking for a best idea to design user permission system area where admin assign access to roles and assign that roles to user. role wise user can or can't access web pages.

initially i have some idea which i like to discuss briefly. just tell me am i in right direction?

suppose my site will have HR related pages, Sales and Account Related pages. so any user can not access HR or Account, Purchase related pages. the way admin give rights that way user can access area.

suppose in first page admin will save all controller name and their action name in master table

for Admin page where i will show all controller and action name along with id hidden.

Say HR Controller

> ```
>   1) PayslipView Action
>
>   2) Payslip Edit Action
> ```

etc

so admin first create few roles like HR,Accounts, Purchase and sales etc.

admin first Select roles from **dropdown**.

below i will show controller wise action name. admin just tick controller name with few action name and save that info in db. where i will save role id and controller id,action id.

this way i can attach controller and action id with roles. when this role will be assign that will be save in db with role id and user id.

at controller level or action level i will write a custom attribute by which i will validate that a specific user has which role and has permission to access this action ?

because i do not want to hard code roles with action like this way

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Producer")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Details(int id) {
    // Only available to users who are Producers AND Editors
}
```

rather i would like to follow this below way

```
public class DynamicRoleAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var controller = httpContext.Request.RequestContext
            .RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var action = httpContext.Request.RequestContext
            .RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        // feed the roles here
        Roles = string.Join("," ,_rolesProvider.Get(controller, action));
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}

[DynamicRoleAuthorize]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{

}
```

but my question is if any developer by mistake change any action or controller name in cs file then how can i manage the whole things. by mistake if any controller name change or action name change then my idea will not work properly.

so please guide me how to design this kind of permission system in asp.net mvc 5 which will have no dependency on controller name or action name. if those name change then also permission should work.

please guide me with idea or some code example to implement in web based product. or tell me other experience developer how they handle this kind of situation with any dependency. looking for best guide line to implement this kind of permission system.

i search google but found no good solution which i can follow. there are ample of articles on various topic related to asp.net mvc but this is very essential part of a any product which not touched much as per my google search i understood.

if anyone got any article links related to this topic then please share url with me for **RBAC system**. if article is on asp.net core mvc then also that will help me to get idea.

thanks

Comment: you searched google but found no good solution. hard to believe. at least you need to explain what are the limitations of Microsoft built-in solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @Felix i am looking for a article or detail guide line which guide me how to design a system as a result admin user can attach roles with action at runtime. just looking for a idea how can i design a UI where all action name will be shown and admin can attach custom roles with action. the drawback would be if action name is change in future by any developer then that will be hard to track and update the name in db.

Comment: Consider CLAIMS as the authorisation mechanism instead (you can still have users in roles but fine tune the claims). What I do is have 4 claims for each controller (Read-Create-Update-Delete) each action has one of those 4 authorisation attributes. You then use the database to match a user to each claim. I set up roles to have a default set of claims so when a user is added to a role they have the default claims added to them. You never have to change your code - just records in the  database

Comment: @pixelda i have no idea how to do or implement in project. can you share some relevant article on this matter to get myself prepare to implement it ? how to attach claims with action from UI where admin can assign claims with action and later assign those claims to user ?

Answer (score 1):

My first inclination was to vote to close this question, because it is looking for an opinion; almost a blog post that will describe how to design a flexible permission system. There are plenty on the web, including Microsoft documentation that I linked to. So, if you googled and couldn't find anything - then you are struggling with what exactly you are looking for...

Fundamentally, the permission system involves actors (usually, users) and securable resources (for example, APIs). The challenge is to be able to assign permissions to users and verify such permissions when the user invokes API. The permission *required* for an API can and should be hardcoded:

```
[FuncPermission("GetHrData")]
public ActionResult Details(int id) {
    // Only available to users that have GetHrData Permission
}
```

And then you define the Roles (groups of users), and assign permissions to Roles. In my mind, you shouldn't hard code the Roles in `Authorize` attribute.

Where do you go from here?

1. Keep your permissions in the database. So, as you develop new functionality, you add new permissions - but your Admin module doesn't change
2. Develop usual admin functionality of users and groups (roles). Preferably, assign permissions to groups; not to users
3. Develop Authorization middleware that will match users' permissions with the permission required to access specific API. `FuncPermissionAttribute` class is part of such middleware.
4. If practical (that is, there aren't that many permissions) - you can store them as role claims in Microsoft Identity and pass them as part of the header. Note that the header has size limit (8-16K on most web servers); so, you may need to get those claims from the database.
5. A user may belong to multiple groups with potentially overlapping permissions; so you need to "flatten" the permissions in order to do the match.

Frankly, there are many other things that you need to consider as well. Developing ERP is complicated enough (even if you are not planning to compete with numerous excellent ERP systems on the market). If you are implementing authorization for the first time - I would suggest to hire somebody who can help you and train you. May not be cheap - but certainly cheaper than ending up with the system that needs to be scrapped and rewritten

Comment: Thanks for reply. I like to know how could i design a UI from where admin user of site can attach permission with user from UI. please put some focus on it. my project will have many action, some of which show read only data. some allow user to insert/update data or may be delete data.

Comment: if possible please suggest some write up with link which help me to understand how to design permission system with asp.net mvc from where user can attach permission with user. thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to do this yourself or (recommended) hire somebody to train and help you

Answer (score 0):

I had a look back through an old MVC 5 project and found this which is a starting point for you.

I assume that each controller has Read/Write/Edit/Delete - or the basic CRUD operations. I created some code that used reflection to look at the project, and for every controller, produced four claims - the controller name and each of the four possible actions. I manually created claims for menu options. In this way, a view can hide or disabled menu options that a user is not allowed to access.

Here is a typical controller action. In my case, a user wants to cancel an invoice which will simply succeed or fail - all of the work is performed in a business model to keep the controller action lightweight. Regardless of whether a view gives a user the rights to cancel an invoice, the belt and braces of having the action implementing a claims attribute ensures the operation is protected from any malicious access.

claims authorsation attribute class show below

```
[ClaimsAuthorize("InvoicesController", "Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CancelInvoice(InvoiceView v)
{
    var user = _userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    await _bs.CancelInvoice_Async(v, ModelState, user.Id);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // state saved
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = v.InvoiceId });
    }

    // not saved
    return View("Edit", v);
}




    /// <summary>
    /// Allows use of an authorisation attribute on controllers and controller methods
    /// </summary>
    public class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private string claimType;
        private string claimValue;
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Authorise using a claim by type (and optional value)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">The Claim Type - Usually [Controller]_[Action]</param>
        /// <param name="value">The Claim Value, usually one of Read | Edit | Create | Delete, or some other relevant value</param>
        public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(string type, string value = "")
        {
            this.ClaimType = type;
            this.ClaimValue = value;
        }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Claim Type - Usually [Controller]_[Action]
        /// </summary>
        public string ClaimType { get => claimType; protected set => claimType = value; }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Claim Value, usually one of Read | Edit | Create | Delete, or some other relevant value
        /// </summary>
        public string ClaimValue { get => claimValue; protected set => claimValue = value; }
    
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            // assume not authorised
            bool isAuthorised = false;
    
            // check user exists
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User != null)
            {
                // get user by claim principle
                var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;
    
                if (user != null && user.HasClaim(ClaimType, ClaimValue))
                {
                    // user has a claim of the correct type
                    isAuthorised = true;
                }
            }
    
            if (isAuthorised)
            {
                filterContext.Result = null;
                base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }
            else
            {
                // we don't use 401 as this will cause a login loop :  base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
                // Forbidden message will be shown
                filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "You are forbidden to access this resource");
            }
        }
    }
```